# cordova webview

Tags: ios, webview, phonegap, cordova

Друзья, кто подскажет как избавиться вот от такого ужасного бэкгроунда в приложении на cordova? Когда тянешь его вниз, появляется вот такое серое поле. А как сделать, чтоб ни сверху, ни снизу оно не появлялось при прокрутке? Может какие-то плагины или теги?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А просто задать фон для body не помогает?

Answer (score 1):

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/config_ref/index.html

В настройках config.xml установите свойство

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю вопрос задан давно, но может кому поможет.
Я решил это, установив максимальную высоту и отключив прокрутку по горизонтале

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Вообще-то такое не должно работать... Ну либо селектор `body` тут вообще лишний.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Спасибо, скажите пожалуйста, куда именно в файле config.xml добавлять <preference>, а то они почему-то не работают, или они будут работать только после сборки?

Comment: Не знаю, я просто ещё раз глянул на удалённый ответ и понял, что в нём парсер проглотил строку xml'я, так что восстановил и исправил форматирование. Вообще, я не уверен, как тот ответ скажется на плавности прокрутки всего. Я бы попробовал просто прописать фон для body - мне кажется, должно сработать.