# Зафиксировать экран Cordova

Tags: phonegap, cordova

Пишу приложение на Cordova. Есть такой момент: если тянуть за экран вниз, он как бы отделяется от от верха, а мне нужны что бы он был на месте. С низом так же. Что можно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562188/178988

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю вопрос задан давно, но может кому поможет. Я решил это, установив максимальную высоту и отключив прокрутку по горизонтали

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Вообще-то такое не должно работать... Ну либо селектор `body` тут вообще лишний.